# DataTable set class and background for a TD

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am having big issues assigning a custom class to a TD in DataTables in order to change the background color based on the value of it. It seems like the class is getting assigned, but I am not able to get the if-statement working.

**Here is my columnDefs**

```
"columnDefs": [ 
    { className: "dt-center test", "targets": [ 7 ] },
  //{ "sClass": "test", "aTargets": [ 7 ] },

    { className: "dt-center", targets: '_all' },
    { className: "dt-justify", targets: '_all'},
    { targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 7], visible: true},
    { targets: '_all', visible: false },
]
```

**Here is my JavaScript If-statement**

```
$(".test").each((index, element) => {
    if (element.innerText >= 0) element.classList.add("green");
    else element.classList.add("red");
});
```

**My CSS**

```
.green {
    background-color: green !important;
}
.red {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated on this matter - It has bugged me out for a while now.

Comment: you are missing an end quote at the `add("green")`

Comment: Thanks, must have happen when I pasted the code in here. I hope it was that simple.

Comment: is it working properly?

Comment: No Alec, It does not work. No solution as of now.

Comment: what is test in this case? I see you are running a for each on it?

Comment: I'd check first whether .test is referring to the right element. We can't tell whether it is or not from the code you've posted. I would set a breakpoint on one of the JS lines and investigate the DOM.

Comment: Can you share the HTML structure of the table, plus js code where you have initialized the datatable?